# Wordpress - List all the post's categories with custom code in the single page

Tags: wordpress, categories

First of all it's supposed to be used in the single page. After the single post I want to display the categories that the post belongs to.

The basic code for this is `<?php the_category(' | '); ?>` which outputs a simple link. Then we have `<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>` which outputs a more specific code (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list):

```
<ul class="post-categories">
    <li>
        <a href="http://myblog.com/category/business" title="View all posts in Business" rel="category tag">Business</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However I need to decompose this code. For example, I want the `<a>` tag to be before the `<li>` tag. I've got a code that does what I want, but it's supposed to display all the categories available in my page, which is:

```
            <?php
                $categories = get_categories();
                foreach($categories as $category)
                {
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->cat_ID); ?>"><li><?php echo $category->name ?> <span class="lower">(<?php echo $category->count ?>)</span></li></a>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
```

Any idea how I can make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not supposed to wrap `<li>` tag with `<a>` tag...  `<a>` is  inline tag and should not cover block. and more than that its unorderd list `<ul>` should be the parent of the `<li>`.

Comment: Since when I can't use `<a>` before `<li>`? God.

Comment: Its the normal flow and `<li>` parents should be the tag the define the **list** like `<ul>` `<ol>`

Comment: I know how to use the `<li>` tag. And `<a>` can go before `<li>` if, for example, you use each li as a box and you want the whole box to be linked.

Comment: you should put the `<a>` inside the `<li>` and give `display: block;` and the `height`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $category = get_the_category($post_id);
    foreach($category as $cat)
    {
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>"><li><?php echo $cat->name ?></li></a>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please add additional details to support the code. Just providing code is not the best way to answer.

Comment: No need. Also, details about how the code was achieved is in the previous answer's comment section.

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_the_category() its return you category objects that you can loop and do with them what you want.

```
$category = get_the_category( /* $post_id */ ); 
print_r($category);
foreach($category as $cat) {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Like I said, it's not supposed to go inside the loop, it's to be used in the single.php page.

Comment: You didn't mention that its not supposed to be outside the loop.  anyway you can always add the `$post_id`

Comment: That outputs arrays and random text. But the `$post_id` reference is helpful. I found the right way using my original code, will post it myself.